# Angular You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file."

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have an angular application with default configuration.When I run npm test it fails stating "Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token.You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file."
I have a file named report.mrt and I am importing it in one file.As a result this error pops up.How could I add a new loader for it in karma.config. npm serve works correctly without any error

Expectation is to make npm test working

Comment: Share us a reproducible sample

Comment: `.mrt` files are not valid files for a browser. The compiler is telling you it does not know how to read it. Try finding a package to read it, or edit it to transform it to JSON or JS or whatever is more suited.